# Find the Post ID of a post from another website

Tags: posts

I wanted to get the Post ID of a post from another website, but it was not in the url, but it was in the Response Header.
[image]

When I output the Response Header, the Post ID does not appear on the output. Do you have a solution for getting the Post ID ?

[image]

Comment: You might be able to use the remote site's REST API. A URL like `https://example.com/wp-json/v2/posts/?slug=the-slug-you-want` would return the post(s) with that slug, and in the post's/posts' JSON objects the ID is available.

Comment: Really Really Thank You Mr Pat j. ♥ 
The solution : https://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/?slug=the-slug-you-want

Answer (score 2):

[WordPress's REST API](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/) should provide the information you need.

If you're after a post with the slug `the-slug-you-want`, then you can request the data about any post(s) with that slug using the URL `https://example.com/wp-json/v2/posts/?slug=the-slug-you-want`. This returns the post(s) with that slug, and in the post's/posts' JSON objects the ID is available.